# Automate variable selection based on varimp in R

Tags: r, r-caret, feature-selection

In R, I have a logistic regression model as follows

```
train_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3)

logit_Model <- train(result~., data=df,
           trControl = train_control,
           method = "glm",
           family=binomial(link="logit"))

calculatedVarImp <- varImp(logit_Model, scale = FALSE)
```

I use multiple datasets that run through the same code, so the variable importance changes for each dataset. Is there a way to get the names of the variables that are less than n (e.g. 1) in the overall importance, so I can automate the removal of those variables and rerun the model.

I was unable to get the information from 'calculatedVarImp' variable by subsetting 'overall' value

```
lowVarImp <- subset(calculatedVarImp , importance$Overall <1)
```

Also, is there a better way of doing variable selection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is very similar to using the `best.glm()` function. Also, if you are interested more in prediction you could use a `randomForest()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the `caret` package. Not sure if you're aware of this, but `caret` has a method for stepwise logistic regression using the Akaike Information Criterion: `glmStepAIC`.

So it iteratively trains a model for every subset of predictors and stops at the one with the lowest AIC.

```
train_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3)

logit_Model <- train(y~., data= train_data,
                     trControl = train_control,
                     method = "glmStepAIC",
                     family=binomial(link="logit"),
                     na.action = na.omit)

logit_Model$finalModel
```

This is as automated as it gets but it may be worth reading this answer about the downsides to this method:

[See Also](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection).

Comment: Whenever I read about step-wise selection it makes me smile, because I think of `fortunes::fortune(119)`. `fortunes` is such a great package. +1 for the [See Also](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection) part

Comment: Just curious: What's so funny about `fortune(119)`?

Comment: I find it entertaining that the two statisticians consider step-wise feature selection (using AIC or similar) to be almost equally valid  as selection of a random number of random features from the data set. This quote alone discouraged me to ever perform step wise selection.

Comment: Ha, now I get it.